# C++ container for heterogeneous POD types

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers

Is there a form of heterogeneous container, that is able to to store for example different primitive types (such as `int`, `float`, `double`)?

Ultimately I'd like to be able to use the elements in calculations without referring to the type explicitly, for example `auto res = a + b`, where the operands `a` and `b` are elements pulled out of the container and could be of same or different types.

Comment: You are looking for a weakly typed programming language. Why do you need to do this in C++? Well, maybe consider Boost's Variant or Any.

Comment: C++ is a statically typed language. Which means that the type of each object is specified at compile time, not runtime. C++ fundamentally does not work as you describe.

Comment: @CodyGray: Rather *"dynamically typed"*, which could still be *"strongly typed"*. Just not *"statically typed"*.

Comment: std::tuple can be used

Comment: @CinCout tuple can only be used if the number of elements is known at compile time. Plus, you should only know the order in which types comes in. If you declare a tuple which has a `float` as its third element, that is something that cannot  change during the execution. I would also suggest `boost variant`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was looking for some way to abstract this, and not having to specify the operand type when operating on it, for avoiding specialized code for each type, but I realize now there's probably no way around this. I'll go with either `variant` or `any`. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With C++17 you can use [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) with any container. With older C++ versions you can use [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/any.html).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <any>

struct A
{
    int a;
    explicit operator int() const { return a; }
};

struct B
{
    double b;
    explicit operator double() const { return b; }
};

int main()
{
    A a{ 5 };
    B b{ 6.};

    std::vector<std::any> v;
    v.push_back(3 );
    v.push_back(4.);
    v.push_back(a );
    v.push_back(b );

    for (auto const e : v)
    {
        if (e.type() == typeid(double))
            std::cout << std::any_cast<double>(e) << std::endl;

        if (e.type() == typeid(B))
            std::cout << (double)std::any_cast<B>(e) << std::endl;
    }
}
```